# Apache odd permission behavior in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

## Short version:

Apache deny access to file at */opt/adminer*, but works as expected if the file served is at */usr/share/adminer/adminer*.

## Longer version:

The package *adminer* installs this apache configuration file:

```
#Apache configuration

Alias /adminer /usr/share/adminer/adminer

<Directory /usr/share/adminer/adminer>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_value include_path .
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

But the *adminer* version provided in *Ubuntu 14.04* is somewhat old, and I decided to download the current version.

I put the *adminer.php* (renamed to *index.php*) file at /opt/adminer, and changed the relevant **paths** in the previous configuration file accordingly.

```
Alias /adminer /opt/adminer
#Alias /adminer /usr/share/adminer/adminer

<Directory /opt/adminer>
#<Directory /usr/share/adminer/adminer>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_value include_path .
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

But this don't work. 
When I use a browser to access the *adminer* web app, I see this:

> ### Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /adminer/ on this server.

In the log file:

> [Thu Dec 10 18:08:15.425548 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31647]
>   mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.0.2.2:49992] AH01626: authorization
>   result of Require all denied: denied
>
> [Thu Dec 10 18:08:15.425671 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31647] 
>   mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 10.0.2.2:49992] AH01626: authorization
>   result of : denied
>
> [Thu Dec 10 18:08:15.425691 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 31647]
>   [client 10.0.2.2:49992] AH01630: client denied by server
>   configuration: /opt/adminer/

But if I copy the *index.php* file from */opt/adminer* to */usr/share/adminer/adminer*, and change the configuration file accordingly, it works flawlessly.

## More info:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ll /opt/adminer/
total 416
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Dez  7 23:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Dez  7 22:10 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 415388 Nov 15 18:50 index.php

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ll /usr/share/adminer/adminer/
total 416
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Dez 10 17:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Dez 10 17:29 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 415388 Dez 10 17:29 index.php
```

Comment: Try running those two `ll` commands with a `-d` flag

Comment: This gives the same info as in the line referring the "." directories above..

Comment: it's supposed to give the permissions of the directories.

Comment: I've always had my web root ownership as www-data:www-data and that has never given me any problems.

Comment: "." is an alias to the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem..

At */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So, by default *Apache* denies access to everything except **/usr/share** and **/var/www**.

So I need to edit the apache2.conf file and also explicitly allow access to **/opt**:

```
<Directory /opt/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

or simply add **Require all granted** inside the *Directory* part of my original configuration file:

```
Alias /adminer /opt/adminer
#Alias /adminer /usr/share/adminer/adminer

<Directory /opt/adminer>
#<Directory /usr/share/adminer/adminer>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted     # <----------

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_value include_path .
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I have to wait two days..

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu server 16.04.1 LTS you have to add line (/etc/apache2/apache2‌​.conf):

```
#put some comment here to know what happend    
Include /etc/adminer/apache.conf
```

I have added this line before:

```
<Directory />
```

and after restarting apache2 everything is working fine.

Before this line was added nothing was working.